# Blender 2.83 not opening

Tags: error

I'm on Windows 10, Intel i7, GeForce 1070. A while back I had Blender on this PC, working fine. But my RAM was corrupted, and after a couple months the problem was fixed. I recently decided to get back into Game Dev, and decided to get Blender again to do a little modeling. But all that happens is the program flashes grey, and it shuts down. I've updated all my drivers, Windows 10 is fully updated, run_debug_gpu is doing nothing anymore. I've uninstalled and reinstalled countless times, including older versions. It just will not open, no matter what. Are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: Try portable .zip Blender versions and try installing a different GPU driver. NVidia may have 2 versions - Game Ready and Studio, make sure you try both.

Comment: I am using a 1070, i7, win 10 as well,  using the latest studio driver with no issues. Try running blender from a command line with  `--debug-all --factory-startup` or use an earlier version